# SharePoint Online - Page layouts for team site templates?

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, publishing-site, team-sites

When I put my site collection (team site template) in edit mode and select the page tab, there's no page layout button like with a publish portal site collection.

[image]

I thought enabling the following two features would enable this functionality:

1. Site Settings -> Site Collection Features -> SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
2. Site Settings -> Site Features -> SharePoint Server Publishing

Unfortunately, this is not the case. So I was wondering if page layouts are not applicable for team sites.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5a7f3e6-47db-473d-955e-52f3eaaa0e5a/change-sharepoint-team-site-page-layout?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding about this. Page layouts are applicable for team sites, but only for publishing pages.

After you create a new team site, the type of homepage is a wiki page. We cannot see "page layout" button in wiki page.

After you activate the publishing feature, there will be a Page library in your team site. The type of new pages created in this new library is publishing page. We can custom page layout in publishing page. Also you can make a publishing page as homepage.

If you want to edit the wiki page, you need to create custom code in SharePoint Designer:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b68308f6-2aa8-4b89-bc5a-5b375e476208/sharepoint-online-create-a-custom-wiki-page-template-with-headings-and-web-parts?forum=sharepointgeneral